# I can't seem to centre align the entry content div in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, alignment

I'm trying to align one large image in the center of the div.entry-content on this page: http://rowanibbeken.co.uk/bankside-power-station-bankside-london (i.e. I don't want the smaller images to effect the centering of the large image) whilst I'd like the purchase button table at the bottom to be in line with the large image. So far the main problem has been the div. After trying every centering method under the sun I'm still unsure why it's shifted to the right and has messed up the alignment of the whole page. If anyone has any advice on this that would be great.
Thanks in advance!
Rowan

Answer (score 0):

Take the images out of the table, add a `clear:both;` to their CSS, and give them each a `margin: 0 auto;`

The clear should make it so that nothing else is on the same line as the image no matter what size it is, and the margin will center them.